# Are some "health" foes weak against Corrosive?

Tags: borderlands-2

Borderlands 2 introduces a telltale yellow Armor bar for Armored foes, generally making it much easier to tell when you should use Fire weapons versus Corrosive ammo. However many Health targets also have armored parts.

Notably there are Spiderants and Hyperion Soldiers like Engineers. Engineers appear to be almost completely covered with armor. Are they weak to corrosion or flame? For Spiderants I know Fire works well on their unarmored thorax but Corrosive works, with reduced damage, on the armored parts (just like it worked in Borderlands 1).

With Hyperion I've had a harder time telling; in the first playthrough it seems both Acid and Fire work servicably, but in the second playthrough elemental effects are more pronounced, so I'd really like to know which element I should use against them.

Are "armored" looking enemies with red health bars still weak to flame (ignoring elemental enemies of course)?

Answer (score 6):

The health bar has to be yellow for corrosive to be extra effective. It still works normally on most normal health bars. Fire is best against most normal health bars (except the ones of fire creatures as they will resist). Shock is great against shields, especially useful in the second playthrough when much more things have shields.

In general you should be able to judge what is effective, what is resisted and what is doing normal damage just by looking at the damage numbers floating around enemies.

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted, but it is correct. Despite their armored appearance, Hyperion Engineers are "flesh" - their red healthbars are tell-tale. This becomes more pronounced in True Vault Hunter Mode, where both positive and negative modifiers to elements become *much* more severe.

Comment: HP bar color is usually reliable for normal enemies, but not so much for bosses who nearly always have red health bars even though some are armored.